# How many people did Snow kill in 'The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes' and who was the third victim?

Tags: the-hunger-games, the-ballad-of-songbirds-and-snakes

In *The Hunger Games: The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes* (2023) Snow mentions that he killed three people.

I'm looking to understand who these individuals were, particularly the third person mentioned in the dialogue towards the film's end.

Any insights into the context and implications of these actions would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snow murders two people with his own hands;

- [Bobbin](https://thehungergames.fandom.com/wiki/Bobbin) (District 8's Tribute) in the arena by bludgeoning.

> [image]

- [Mayfair Lipp](https://thehungergames.fandom.com/wiki/Mayfair_Lipp) (the Mayor's blabbermouth daughter) with a rifle.

> [image]

He then accidentally confesses to the murder of Sejanus (e.g. by sending information about his treachery to the Capital), making that his third kill.

---

We see this all explicitly confirmed in the [source novel](https://24th-hunger-games.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ballad_of_Songbirds_and_Snakes).

> *Bobbin sprang at him again, aiming the knife at his face. Coriolanus’s fingers closed around a two-by-four, and he brought it up, catching Bobbin in the temple hard, sending him to his knees. And then he was on his feet, using the board like a club, bringing it down again and again without being sure where it made contact.*

And

> *Coriolanus reflexively reached for the Peacekeeper rifle and fired toward Mayfair’s voice. She gave a cry, and there was the sound of her collapsing to the floor.*

And

> *She ignored his injury. “Person you killed. You said you killed three people this summer.”
>
> Coriolanus bit at the end of the splinter to pull it out with his teeth, buying a moment of time. Who, indeed? The answer was Sejanus, of course, but he couldn’t admit to that.
>
> “Can you get this out?” He held out his hand, wiggling the compromised fingernail, hoping to distract her.
> “Let me see.” She examined his splinter. “So, Bobbin, Mayfair . . . who’s the third?”*

Comment: Interestingly, he also killed Jessup, by getting Lyssie to send water to him, but he does not seem to count that. Because he views Lyssie as having been the one to do it? Because it was an accident, and he just wanted to drive Jessup away from Lucy? He does not count the people that Lucy poisoned, either, despite having given her the poison with the express intent of her using it to kill the other Tributes. Then again, with someone as self-serving as Snow, it's no surprise that he only counts the cases where he killed directly (Mayfair, Bobbin) or where he felt guilty (Sejanus).

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Jessup was already a dead man walking. And Lucy killed those men, not him.

Comment: The commander killed Sejanus, but Snow still held himself responsible because he had arranged for it to happen. And  even if Jessup was going to die anyway, Snow still killed him.